# How do I return variables in watchEffect from vue 3 setup function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```js
setup(props) {
  const id = ref(props.id)
  watchEffect(() => {
    const { data1, data2, data3 } = getData(id)
  })

  return { data1, data2, data3 }
}
```

This is just a portion of the code, the **watchEffect**, **ref** and **getData** are all imported but the return function below says data1, data2, data3 are undefined, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `refs` outside the function:

```
setup(props) {
  const id = ref(props.id);
  const data1 = ref(null);
  const data2 = ref(null);
  const data3 = ref(null);

  watchEffect(() => {
    [data1.value, data2.value, data3.value] = getData(id)

  })

  return { data1, data2, data3 }
}
```

And if you return an object:

```
setup(props) {
  const id = ref(props.id);
  const data1 = ref(null);
  const data2 = ref(null);
  const data3 = ref(null);

  watchEffect(() => {
    {
      data1: data1.value,
      data2: data2.value,
      data3: data3.value
    } = getData(id)

  })

  return { data1, data2, data3 }
}
```

I don't have the rest of your code but I'm sure it can be more optimized...

Comment: I returned an object from the getData function, so I have to destructure it as an object in the setup function

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't remember if it's `data1: data1.value` or `data1.value: data1`. Try both and please tell me which one is good :)